# Script that replaces one letter with another on a keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a script that will replace one letter with another when writing something outside the console. I have already found a script that would "globally" interact on Windows 10 when executed.

```
import win32api
while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x52)
    if a < 0:
        win32api.Beep(3000, 1000)
```

Is there a command for replacing a letter via layout changes? Or maybe there is a simpler solution?